# passenger_apache2 cookbook fails

Tags: apache, chef-infra, passenger, cookbook

I attempting to deploy a number of cookbooks to configure Apache2 and Passenger on Ubuntu 14.04. Below is the list of cookbooks I am installing in the order in which they appear in the run_list:

```
build-essential 2.1.3,
apt 2.6.1,
iptables 0.14.1,
logrotate 1.7.0,
apache2 2.0.0,
vim 1.1.2,
passenger_apache2 2.2.3
```

I am bootstrapping my vagrant vm from my development workstation and the cookbooks all appear to get installed with no errors, except when it gets to the passenger_apache2 cookbook. I can provide the entire extensive output, but I believe the following is the informative part of the output:

```
STDERR: [Wed Jan 21 14:05:17.027610 2015] [core:warn] [pid 26648] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
node.vagrantup.com (2)No such file or directory: AH02297: Cannot access directory '/etc/apache2/${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/' for log file '${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/other_vhosts_access.log' defined at /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/other-vhosts-access-log.conf:2
node.vagrantup.com AH00014: Configuration check failed
```

I have seen only a couple of discussions indicating an issue with the $HOME environment variable not being set for the daemonized chef-client. However, I am unclear on how to remedy this situation. I would appreciate any insight the community can provide as I learn how to use Chef.

Thx

UPDATE: Viewing the passenger_apache2 cookbook [README](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/passenger_apache2), apparently this cookbook is not yet supported on Ubuntu 14.04 due to the use of Apache 2.4 in that version of the OS. Further, I see I missed an error in the output which says:

```
WARNING: Apache doesn't seem to be compiled with the 'prefork', 'worker' or 'event' MPM
node.vagrantup.com Phusion Passenger has only been tested on Apache with the 'prefork', the
node.vagrantup.com 'worker' and the 'event' MPM. Your Apache installation is compiled with
node.vagrantup.com the '' MPM. We recommend you to abort this installer and to recompile
node.vagrantup.com Apache with either the 'prefork', the 'worker' or the 'event' MPM.
```

Curious to know if anyone is deploying passenger on Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache 2.4 using Chef Server. If so, how?

UPDATE 2: I can not get this working with the supposedly supported Ubuntu 12.04 either. Would really like to know if anybody has this cookbook working and if so, how.

Comment: We are on CentOS not ubuntu but we ditched the passenger cookbook and just run the passenger gems from a cookbook as it seemed a bit less fraught with peril. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks, Wyatt. Are you able to share your cookbook for installing the passenger gem?

Comment: With the caveats that my linux, chef and ruby skills are horrible here is the meaty part: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1ba9784760913810b820

Comment: Thank you, sir! Yours can't be worse than mine! :) I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by taking the following actions:

1. Downloaded the latest [Apache2 cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/apache2) and uploaded it to my Chef server
2. Downloaded the latest [Passenger_Apache2 cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/passenger_apache2).
3. Uploading the new Passenger_Apache2 cookbook failed with an error indicating that there was a dependency on Apache 1.0 that was unmet. I then modified the metadata.rb file of the Passenger_Apache2 cookbook and changed the following line:

`depends 'apache2', '~> 1.0'`

to:

`depends 'apache2', '~> 3.0'`

Now when I bootstrap my chef node, it installs passenger with no errors. Hope this helps others.